# I want to hear Zelazny's voice, can I ask about it here?

Tags: discussion

Being a big fan of Roger Zelazny's work I'd love to hear how he sounded. I've spent some time searching but didn't manage to find anything. Would a question "Is there any recording of Roger Zelazny's voice available on the Internet" or "Where can I find any recording of Roger Zelazny's voice on the Internet?" a valid question for this SE site?

Comment: Yes. Its perfectly reasonable. Ask it.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TRQ4wKLfYbc

Comment: @Richar: sweet, but "This video contains content from SME, who has blocked it in your country on copyright grounds." :(

Comment: If you're outside the US might I suggest you install [Hola for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hola-better-internet/gkojfkhlekighikafcpjkiklfbnlmeio?hl=en) or [Hola for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/collections/hola_networks/t/) allowing you to view it from any location.

Comment: @MaurycyZarzycki Don't forget, that across entire Stack Echange network, questions titles in question form are less encouraged than titles in sentence form. So, rather "_Recording of Roger Zelazny's voice available on the Internet_" (without "_Is there_" or "_Where can I find_" etc.).

Comment: @trejder Can you reference this? From what I see they are pretty much as popular and I can't recall any discussion about it from the top of my head.

Comment: @MaurycyZarzycki Nope. Same here. I just have this in my head, that I heard this somewhere in SE. I'm following this rule, editing questions, I find to non-question form and on every SE site, where I don't have enough rep, so my edit must be peer-reviewed, I've never got any edit rejected or any comment, that I shouldn't do this. So, for me this is an unspoken rule. Unfortunately, I can't provide any credit for it and I might be wrong as well.

Answer (score 13):

Seems like a reasonable question to me. It's answerable and it's about SF.

Comment: Seconded. There's no reason (within reason) why you can't ask a question about **the author** of a science fiction series